# SOLR Search result order is different due to the query _val_:__boost function

Tags: solr, content-search

After upgrading the project to `Sitecore10.2` SOLR search result is different in order due to the `query _val_:__boost function`.
I have investigated the issue and found out that in `Sitecore 9.0.2` our SOLR search query was:

```
..........AND (-_template:("083a4d2a38694013a9e2d18c05da70ae") *:*))
```

and in Sitecore 10.2 SOLR search query is:

```
..........AND (-_template:("083a4d2a38694013a9e2d18c05da70ae") *:*)) AND _val_:__boost
```

There is one more extra condition at last in the query i.e. `AND _val_:__boost`. I have gone through the Sitecore documents on [Search result boosting](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/platform-administration-and-architecture/search-result-boosting.html) and found that
`In Sitecore XP 10.0.0 or later, item-level boosting relies on index-time scoring factors that are indexed in the __boost field and combined with the query score using the query _val_:__boost function.`

I have also tried the below approach one by one but did not get any success:

1. Disabled the `boostingManager` in `Sitecore.ContentSearch.config` file.
2. Removed the `StaticItemBoostResolver` processor in `Sitecore.ContentSearch.config` file.
3. Removed all the locations included in `includedLocations` in `Sitecore.ContentSearch.config` file.

`_val_:__boost function` is affecting our search result order and I want to remove the function from our search query.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the c sharp code you're writing to query?

Comment: You most likely have some boosting code that behaves differently than previous versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have raised a support ticket to the Sitecore for the above issue and they suggested me the two approaches:

**Sitecore Response:**

First of all, let me comment on the approaches you have already tried:

1. Disabled the `boostingManager` in `Sitecore.ContentSearch.config` file.
   The `disabled` attribute is ignored and has no effect on the behavior.
2. Removed the `StaticItemBoostResolver` processor in `Sitecore.ContentSearch.config` file.
   This was a step in the right direction.
   It means Sitecore will now ignore the value of the Boost field `('{93D1B217-B8F4-462E-BABF-68298C9CE667}')` of the item.
3. Removed all the location included in `includedLocations` in `Sitecore.ContentSearch.config` file.
   If no location is specified then all locations are scanned.

To achieve the desired behavior comment out all of the processors in the `<indexing.resolveItemBoost>` pipeline and rebuild the search indexes.

Alternatively, restore the original state of the pipeline.
Clear the value of the Boost field `('{93D1B217-B8F4-462E-BABF-68298C9CE667}')` for every item.
Remove any boosting rules under
`/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Indexing and Search/Item Rules`
`/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Indexing and Search/Global Rules`
Rebuild the search indexes.

The latter approach is recommended as it does not require changing the behavior of the product.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see it's a default now in Sitecore 10.X.

Looks like it's hardcoded in `SolrQueryMapper` and cannot be easily removed when you use Sitecore Content Search (see `BoostQuery` part):

```
public override SolrCompositeQuery MapQuery(IndexQuery query)
{
  SolrQueryMapper.SolrQueryMapperState state = new SolrQueryMapper.SolrQueryMapperState((IEnumerable<IExecutionContext>) this.Parameters.ExecutionContexts);
  return new SolrCompositeQuery(BoostQuery(Visit(query.RootNode, state)), state.FilterQuery, state.AdditionalQueryMethods, state.VirtualFieldProcessors, state.FacetQueries, state.ExecutionContexts);
}
```

and `BoostQuery` uses internally `BoostByDocumentFieldSolrQuery` which adds

```
string.Format("_val_:{0}", fieldName);
```

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to implement some suggestions provided by you and Michel West. I have also raised the support ticket to Sitecore for the same.

Comment: Let us all know what they answer